# adding fade transition to images using jquery

Tags: jquery, image, fade, transition

This question has been asked here, [Image Replacement (gallery style) with Fade-In's / Fade-Out's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1289150/image-replacement-gallery-style-with-fade-ins-fade-outs)

This is the script http://www.webdesignerwall.com/demo/jquery/img-replacement.html

But, I'm not sure if it accomplishes what I want, I can't get it to work.

I just want to get a smooth cross fade transition between this image replacement. I've been searching and messing with picture gallery scripts all night.

Any help?

Comment: welcome to SO , i also joined very recently and learned alot here , sure you will be too, this is very nice place to learn and get updated

Comment: there are lot of plugins already available to do this kind of stuff...just google it..

Comment: Thanks, yep, been googling all night, finally turned to SO...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tvanfosson suggested something like this in his answer to the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1289150/image-replacement-gallery-style-with-fade-ins-fade-outs) you noted:

http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/SH5Q9/

The basic idea is to wrap a `<div>` around the the large image and then apply the `fadeOut()` and `fadeIn()` effects to that `<div>`.

Also, you would do well to set yourself up on http://jsfiddle.net, it is a great tool for playing around with things and makes it easy to show people on SO what you've tried already.

Comment: When I get 15 more points I will vote you up!! I wish I new about jsfiddle.net going into this project!! Thank you!

Comment: Ok, I got it working, but it's not quite what I needed and I just don't see what I'm missing here. I really only want the next image to fade in and not have the first image fade out. No matter what i try to change in the code, so far it just breaks it completely... Any ideas? Thanks again!

Comment: You're looking for something more like this one http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/UaWJk/? That one uses <div>s with backgrounds, one positioned on top of the other, the top <div> gets the new image as a background and then it is animated from transparent to full opacity; there's a bit of clean up in the `.animate` callback to put things back into place for the next run.

Comment: Wow, that was quick, genius! This is perfect, I can't thank you enough!!

Comment: I hope my ignorance is not getting annoying here... I may have spoke too soon, it works great in fiddle, but not once I plug it all into dreamweaver. Here is my development server:
http://jnets.endoftheinternet.org/dev3

Any chance you could look at the source and see what I'm doing wrong. All I did was put it in it's own container div, but it didn't work without that either. 

: (

Thanks again

Comment: All the stuff that's in `js/fader.js` should be in the main HTML file and it should be wrapped in `$(document).ready(function() { /* All the js/fader.js stuff goes here */ });`. The `$(document).ready()` bit queues up a function to be run as soon as the DOM is ready for manipulation. You might want to spend a bit of time at http://docs.jquery.com/ to help get your head around jQuery.

Comment: Ah.. got it! I feel like such a noob. I've done a bit with java-script, but I am new to jquery.. I will definitely consult the docs moving forward! Thank you so much!!